# Using the apostrophe for PHP associative array element's name

Tags: php, arrays

Hi I've been trying to figure out how to put something like  Joe's Fruits into a PHP array something like this:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'Fruitland' => '3ddlskdf3',
'Joe's Fruits' => 'dddfdfer3',
);
?>
```

Using the above for example (stackoverflow's code color should tell you this by now), the array will take it as 'Joe' between the two apostrophes instead of the whole 'Joe's Fruits' is there any way I can do this without just calling it 'Joes Fruits'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape quotes with a backslash (`\`):

```
<?php
$arr = array(
'Fruitland' => '3ddlskdf3',
'Joe\'s Fruits' => 'dddfdfer3',
);
?>
```

You can also simply do:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
"Fruitland" => "3ddlskdf3",
"Joe's Fruits" => "dddfdfer3",
);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, (that was a quick!) and helpful reply ^_^

EDIT: If you don't mind, I hope I can squeeze in another PHP question:
header("Location: ".$variable.".html") is this legal? Doing a concatenation like this?

Answer (score 2):

**[PHP strings manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)** is very useful for ones who just started to learn.
Along with **[strings functions list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)** it covers half of the necessary knowledge.